# Expository articles on Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am about to start learning Algebraic Number Theory and thus was looking for some expository articles on this subject. So far I have found two such articles:

1. Dickson, L. E.. (1917). Fermat's Last Theorem and the Origin and Nature of the Theory of Algebraic Numbers. Annals of Mathematics, 18(4), 161–187. http://doi.org/10.2307/2007234
2. Mazur, Barry. (2008). Algebraic Numbers. has appeared as a chapter in the book The Princeton Companion for Mathematics, by Timothy Gowers, June Barrow-Green, Imre Leader (Editors), American Mathematical Society (2008).  http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/algebraic.numbers.April.30.pdf

I wish to read more such articles before I start solving Marcus's book. So, I will be happy to know about more such articles.

Comment: I assume you took to heart Mazur's recommendation of Gauss and Davenport.

Comment: @roysmith yes it is so.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317083

This article is great! It uses reciprocity laws as a guiding theme through some basic ideas of class field theory, in an attempt to 'go back and figure out the number theory that lay behind all those cohomology groups.'

> What is a Reciprocity Law?
>
> B. F. Wyman
>
> The American Mathematical Monthly
>
> Vol. 79, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1972), pp. 571-586

Comment: Yes, it's nice article. I have a curiosity : "Why do most 1 semester courses on Algebraic number theory end before getting into class field theory?". Can you satisfy this curiosity?

Comment: @rationalbeing, a one-semester course already has so much material to cover that it is usually not feasible to reach class field theory except maybe to say briefly something about the main theorems; certainly there's no time to "get into" class field theory in depth.  If you take an algebraic number theory course, or later try to teach such a course, you'll understand why.  Your question is sort of like asking why a first calculus course doesn't get to Stokes' theorem.

Comment: @KConrad what would you call the part of Algebraic number theory before class field theory? Just curious to know the two main parts in which one would divide whole of Algebraic number theory.

Comment: my own undereducated guess might be that it's more like 'algebraic number theory' as the body of literature/techniques/problems, with class field theory at/as its heart (see also the first book of the number theory trilogy by Kato et al., https://books.google.com/books?id=lARCMo8z5uoC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @rationalbeing, just google all the books on algebraic number theory you can find and look at the table of contents before they reach class field theory (many don't even get to that point).  You'll see what is covered. I would just call it algebraic number theory. It doesn't have another  standard name.  Highlights include unique factorization of ideals, the ideal class group, the unit theorem, ramification (discriminant/different), features of Galois extensions (decomposition/inertia groups, Frobenius elements), and some examples (e.g., quadratic and cyclotomic fields) and applications.

Comment: @KConrad see the problem is that, as a small project, I am going to study algebraic number theory before class field theory but I don't find it pleasing to call my report "Some topic in Algebraic Number Theory" since it's really long title. Any suggestions? Do you think "Number Fields" would make a better title? Sorry for unnecessary botheration.

Comment: Not only is the first title long, but it's awkward in English. (I can't judge how the analogue of it in your native language would sound, or maybe you are going to write it in English.) The second one definitely sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend "Fermat's Last Theorem A Genetic Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory" by Harold Edwards: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387902302  See also the first answer to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387705/preparations-for-reading-algebraic-number-theory-by-serge-lang

Comment: I asked my guide about this book by Edwards a couple of months ago and he plainly rejected to comment and asked me to solve Marcus's book. Have you read this book by Prof. Edward? Can you give your personal opinion/review about this book?

Comment: How do you "solve" a book?

Comment: Here https://books.google.ru/books?id=i2mu7jg6OHEC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=Fermat%27s+Last+Theorem+A+Genetic+Introduction+to+Algebraic+Number+marvelous&source=bl&ots=vIRfyiekuo&sig=7HckrnU73j-S9VCO0xQzJDIMQ0g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif1Ovh0-jMAhVKEpoKHXmDBhEQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=Fermat%27s%20Last%20Theorem%20A%20Genetic%20Introduction%20to%20Algebraic%20Number%20marvelous&f=false this book is called "marvelous". Another, not so favorable review, is here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183548007 I read some sections of the book many years ago as a amateur and liked it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I meant to solve the exercises in the book.

Comment: @rationalbeing  Marcus' book is very rich in instructive exercises, except for one big problem: his avoidance of the basic concept of localization (even just for integral domains) at a prime ideal or multiplicative set causes too many of his proofs and definitions to be very "global" in nature, preventing the possibility of instantly reducing certain tasks to the case of dvr's where various matters simplify tremendously.  For this reason, I recommend to first study Pierre Samuel's book "Algebraic Theory of Numbers", solve many exercises there, and use Marcus' book for more practice.

Comment: @nfdc23 yes, you are right. Marcus writes in foreword "...Thus  I  have  avoided  local  methods with  no  apparent disadvantages  except  possibly... Any  awkwardness  therein  can  be  taken  by  the  reader  as  motivation  to  learn  about  localization". Though the motivation for both Marcus's and Samuel's books is Fermat's Last Theorem, but both have adopted different ways. I will read first chapter from both books and then will try to build my opinion that which approach I am comfortable with. Thanks.